# Pyspark / Snowpark SQL Error: Cumulative window frame unsupported for function LAG,

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a bunch of dataframes all containing the same columns; `id, current_ind, change_date`.

Sample Input 1:

| id | current_ind | change_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-06-20 |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-06-20 |
| 1 | 5 | 2023-06-20 |

Sample Input 2:

| id | current_ind | change_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-04-20 |
| 2 | 3 | 2022-05-20 |
| 2 | 4 | 2023-06-20 |

I want to combine all of them, to create a new dataframe with the following output:

| id | old_ind | new_ind | change_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 2021-06-20 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2022-06-20 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | 2023-06-20 |
| 2 | 0 | 2 | 2021-04-20 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 2022-05-20 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 2023-06-20 |

What I tried:

```
union_df = df1.union(df2)
window_spec = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('change_date')

df = union_df.withColumn('old_ind', lag(col("current_ind")).over(window_spec))
```

This gives the correct `old_ind`. But I do not know how to get the `new_ind`.

```
df = df.withColumn('new_ind', lag(col("current_ind")).over(prev_win.rowsBetween(Window.currentRow, Window.unboundedFollowing)))

df.select("id", "old_ind", "new_ind", "change_date")
```

This returns an error: `Cumulative window frame unsupported for function LAG`

Or is there another way without using Window functions too?

Comment: If you go on Snowflake UI at Query History you should be able to see the query triggered behind the Dataframe. I would be curios to see how the query looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something here, but is not the `new_ind` equal to `current_id` for each row?

Ie

```
df1 = snf_session.create_dataframe([[1, 1, "2021-06-20"], [1, 2, "2022-06-20"], [1, 5, "2023-06-20"]], schema=['id', 'current_ind', 'change_date'])
df2 = snf_session.create_dataframe([[2, 2, "2021-04-20"], [2, 3, "2022-05-20"], [2, 4, "2023-06-20"]], schema=['id', 'current_ind', 'change_date'])
union_df = df1.union(df2)

from snowflake.snowpark import Window
window_spec = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('change_date')

df = union_df.withColumn('old_ind', F.lag(F.col("current_ind"), default_value=0).over(window_spec))
df.with_column('new_ind', F.col('current_ind')).show()
----------------------------------------------------------------

|"ID"  |"CURRENT_IND"  |"CHANGE_DATE"  |"OLD_IND"  |"NEW_IND"  |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|2     |2              |2021-04-20     |0          |2          |
|2     |3              |2022-05-20     |2          |3          |
|2     |4              |2023-06-20     |3          |4          |
|1     |1              |2021-06-20     |0          |1          |
|1     |2              |2022-06-20     |1          |2          |
|1     |5              |2023-06-20     |2          |5          |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```